# Android send mpegts streams over udp

Tags: android, eclipse, udp, gstreamer

I want to receive `mpegts` over `udp` in my android application. I am using `gstreamer` for that. Right now, I am trying to send the mpegts stream from vlc player from the same computer over udp.

In my android application, I am giving the uri **udp://10.0.2.2:1234** but the application gives error **Could not get/set settings from/on resource**. I have tried to get solutions from internet, but no luck so far.

Comment: Please help, if anyone has any slightest idea regarding this.

Comment: Found that I might be giving the udp format wrong. But not getting the correct answer. Can any one please please help?

Comment: I've used the udp for one of my projects to start (I'm not 100% sure, but from my personal memories) below 2.3 the UDP is not functional everywhere. Then I noticed that some of my devices came to send UDP packets base, while another needed wifi locking.

I hope it can help you

Answer (score 0):

1) UDP address range is from 224.0.0.0 to 239.255.255.255, so you cannot use 10.x.x.x

2) After you deal with adresses, refer to [this](https://code.google.com/p/boxeeremote/wiki/AndroidUDP) link to deal with programmatic part:

> **Getting the Broadcast Address** You need to access the wifi manager to get the DHCP info and construct a broadcast address from that:

```
InetAddress getBroadcastAddress() throws IOException {
    WifiManager wifi = mContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    DhcpInfo dhcp = wifi.getDhcpInfo();
    // handle null somehow

    int broadcast = (dhcp.ipAddress & dhcp.netmask) | ~dhcp.netmask;
    byte[] quads = new byte[4];
    for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
      quads[k] = (byte) ((broadcast >> k * 8) & 0xFF);
    return InetAddress.getByAddress(quads);
}
```

> **Sending and Receiving UDP Broadcast Packets** Having constructed the broadcast address, things work as normal. The following code would
>   send the string data over broadcast and then wait for a response:

```
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(PORT);
socket.setBroadcast(true);
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data.getBytes(), data.length(),
    getBroadcastAddress(), DISCOVERY_PORT);
socket.send(packet);

byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
socket.receive(packet);
```